# why ajax jquery didnt work if get value(where clause) from input

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have data to be displayed in the 'Modal'. The data was obtained from the query I tried in phpmyadmin and it worked. I also tried it with a query with the time statement 'CURRENT_DATE' and it worked too. But when I tried it with time information with manual input (months and years manually inputted) the query didn't work.

this my query first and its stil work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".monitor").click(function(){

        $("#list-format").html("");
        let nama_puskesmas = $(this).data('nama');
        let id_puskesmas = $(this).data('id');


        $.ajax({
            url     : 'get_data',
            method  : 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : {id_puskesmas:id_puskesmas},
            success : function(response){

                $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                    $("#list-format").append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
                });

                $("#title-modal").html(nama_puskesmas);
                $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');



            }



        })      

    })
</script>
```

this my controller (work)

```
public function get_data(){
    $id_puskesmas = $this->input->post('id_puskesmas',TRUE);

    $data = $this->app_model->ambil200($id_puskesmas);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

this model (work)

```
    function ambil200($id){

        $query = $this->db->query
("select tb_format.format from tb_format where tb_format.id not in
(select penyakit.format from penyakit where penyakit.id_puskesmas =$id 
 group by penyakit.format having MAX(MONTH(penyakit.waktu_upload)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE))");


        return $query->result();


    }
```

and now i want to change query like this . 
the ajax jquery code is the same as above but, the controller and the model are different

controller (didnt work) ( i changed get_data , i changed it too into ajax code)

```
public function get_data_status(){
    $id_puskesmas = $this->input->post('id_puskesmas',TRUE);
    $year = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $month = $this->input->post('bulan');
    $data = $this->app_model->post_data($id_puskesmas,$year,$month);
    //die(print_r($data));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

model(new query didnt work) . the diferent is input $month and $year.

```
public function post_data($id,$year=null,$month=null){
    if($year == null){
        $year = date("Y");
        }
        if($month == null){
        $month = date("m");
        }


    $query = $this->db->query("select tb_format.format 
        from tb_format 
        where tb_format.id not in
        (select penyakit.format from penyakit where penyakit.id_puskesmas =$id
        AND YEAR(waktu_upload) = '$year' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '$month'  
        group by penyakit.format)
        ");

    //die(print_r($query));
    return $query->result();
}
```

this data not showed , can someone help me ?

Comment: I think the query you have written is wrong. Try removing single quotes from your query and concatinate them or use single quotes in $query select and double in variable.

Comment: ("select tb_format.format 
        from tb_format 
        where tb_format.id not in
        (select penyakit.format from penyakit where penyakit.id_puskesmas =$id
        AND YEAR(waktu_upload) = '$year' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '$month'  
        group by penyakit.format)
        ")    you mean i cant use sub query ? or how ? i dont understand

Comment: and now i know my data input $month and $year not inputted

Comment: query("SELECT tb_format.format FROM tb_format WHERE tb_format.id NOT IN (SELECT penyakit.format FROM penyakit WHERE penyakit.id_puskesmas=$id AND YEAR(waktu_upload)='".$year."' AND MONTH(waktu_upload)='".$month."' GROUP BY penyakit.format))

Comment: syntac error bro . i used my query and i try on phpmyadmin its works

Comment: Ok it seems like it works

Comment: i think this parsing is not problem , because i using it in other query and its still work ,

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you checked the network tab in your browser? Is there any response from the request?